# Unable to install DFS Namespaces feature on 2008R2/SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

I have a totally fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition and have applied SP1 to it (not slipstream).

It is a member of company domain and I'm logged on as domain administrator.

Now I'm trying to install the full suite of DFS roles. I can install them all except for "DFS Namespaces". When trying to install this role it gives me an error code of `0x80070643`. Then asks me to reboot before trying again. Of course I have tried it numerous times and always hit this error.

I've taken a screenshot of the error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kld33.png

Here is a dump of the ServerManager.log file: http://pastebin.com/a2aNJmLq

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps under this KB ([MSKB 0x80070643](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958052) ) and look at the logs created.
Hope it will point you in the right direction. If you want you can post it here and i will have a look at them.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Enable the automatic updates service, Make sure BITS is running, make sure your clock is synched to the correct time, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I did both of these and it worked perfect. I didn't attempt to install DFS Name Spaces until after doing both of these suggestions. Thank you to both Hostbits and Scott Kardos. Saved me hours of time.

"Enable the automatic updates service, Make sure BITS is running, make sure your clock is synched to the correct time, then try again."

And

"Check to make sure the following services aren't disabled. My coworkers and I had this issue for weeks and finally tracked it down to a vendor's GPO disabling a service. Really the only one you need to check is Remote Registry since the others are kinda required. Remote Registry,Security Accounts Manager, Server, Workstation"

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the following services aren't disabled.  My coworkers and I had this issue for weeks and finally tracked it down to a vendor's GPO disabling a service.  Really the only one you need to check is Remote Registry since the others are kinda required.

Remote Registry

Security Accounts Manager

Server

Workstation